# hypertable core data structure

Tags: bigtable, hypertable

I'm looking for the implementation of the multi-dimensional map (or the LSM Tree), but I'm not able to find out which class correspond to the implementation of it, anyone knows that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you unpack the sources, then you find all the files in src/cc/Hypertable/RangeServer:

CellCache.h/CellCache.cc: the in-memory storage (a std::map with a custom memory allocator)

CellStoreV6.h/CellStoreV6.cc: the on-disk storage